# Proof that a density proportional to Gaussian is Gaussian

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, pattern-recognition

I try to develop Bayesian estimation for one dimensional Gaussian with unknown $\mu$ and known $\sigma$. I got 
\begin{align}
p(x|D) &= \int p(x|\mu)p(\mu|D) d\mu  \\
       &=\int \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\frac{1}{\sigma_n\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mu-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}\right)^2\right)d\mu  \\
       &= \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma\sigma_n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(x-\mu_n\right)^2}{\sigma^2+\sigma_n^2}\right)f(\sigma,\sigma_n)  \\
       &\text{ where }  \\
f(\sigma,\sigma_n) &= \int \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2+\sigma_n^2}{\sigma^2\sigma_n^2}\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma_n^2x+\sigma^2\mu_n}{\sigma^2+\sigma_n^2}\right)^2\right)d\mu
\end{align}

Now, It says that $p(x|D)$ is proportional to 
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(x-\mu_n\right)^2}{\sigma^2+\sigma_n^2}\right)$$ 
as a function of x and hence $p(x|D)$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma^2+\sigma_n^2$.

I am asking for an explanation and/or proof for why $p(x|D)$ is proportional to the $\exp$ term $\Rightarrow p(x|D)$ distibuted normally.

Edit: this answer I got is general. I am asking for an explanation for this case.

Comment: Hint: given that all densities must represent a total probability of $1$, what are the possible constants of proportionality?

Comment: can you elaborate? I have x in $f(\sigma,\sigma_n)$, so it is not clear because this is not a constant.

Comment: Better: I found another thread with an expansive answer.

Comment: can you explaing in more details? this is exp times something that is not constant because there is x in $f(\sigma,\sigma_n)$. Thus, I don't understand.

Comment: Even though $x$ appears in the formula for $f$, $f$ does not depend on $x$.  If you solve the integral in $f$ this will be clear.

Comment: Can you show how to integrate this and get that $f$ does not depend on $x$? thank you.

Comment: Also, Can someon remove the duplication mark? this is not the same question and the other question is too general and don't address this case.